# Changing initial view controller and getting error 'Could not load NIB in bundle'

Tags: uiviewcontroller, nib

I am trying to change the initial view controller on load. Although for some reason I am getting the error: `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle`

I notice there are a few questions like this but none have solved the problem for me and none where trying to change the initial VC.

Can someone please help?

Comment: update the code accordingly where u getting crash

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? I am getting the crash on loading the VC

Comment: show the load sequence. you've probably got a name mismatch between a VC and its nib file.

Answer (score 2):

This was simply fixed by just cleaning the project!

Comment: The same happened to me and fixed after a clean & build. Thanks

Comment: Lol.. Braking my head for 10 minutes.. Thanks!